# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext after upgrading spring boot version to 2.6.6 from 2.2.4

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, junit4, vaadin8

I am trying to upgrade the spring boot version from 2.2.4 to 2.6.6. I'm able to compile the application successfully and I'm able to start the application. But when I'm trying to run the tests, all the tests are failing with one error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve @EnableAutoConfiguration base packages

I'm getting the same error for all the tests.

Here is my main pom file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
        <groupId>com.iodine.imc</groupId>
        <artifactId>imc</artifactId>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <modules>
            <module>imc-core</module>
            <module>imc-restapi</module>
            <module>imc-ui</module>
        </modules>
    
        <name>imc-parent</name>
        <description>IMC</description>
    
        <prerequisites>
            <maven>3.0</maven>
        </prerequisites>
    
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.6</version>
            <relativePath />
        </parent>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>build.properties</include>
                    </includes>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>build.properties</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-dao</artifactId>
                            <version>2.0.8</version>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                            <version>2.7.0-01</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                            <version>3.0.0-01</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                            <version>5.8.2</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>groovy-vaadin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>groovy-vaadin</artifactId>
                            <version>0.1</version>
                        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
                            <type>pom</type>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <additionalProjectnatures>
                            <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.core.groovyNature</projectnature>
                        </additionalProjectnatures>
                        <sourceIncludes>
                            <sourceInclude>**/*.groovy</sourceInclude>
                        </sourceIncludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <parallel>classes</parallel>
                        <threadCount>5</threadCount>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*Test.*</include>
                            <include>**/*Test*.java</include>
                            <include>**/*Spec.*</include>
                            <include>**/*Spec.groovy</include>
                            <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
                            <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                        </includes>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/Abstract*.*</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <useDefaultDelimiters>true</useDefaultDelimiters>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.8.5</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.0.1746</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
                        <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
                        <version>7.0.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <suppressionFile>owasp-false-positives.xml</suppressionFile>
                            <failBuildOnCVSS>8</failBuildOnCVSS>
                            <assemblyAnalyzerEnabled>false</assemblyAnalyzerEnabled>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
```

Here is my core pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>imc</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.iodine.imc</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>imc-core</artifactId>
    <name>imc-core</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0-01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.58</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.58</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.25</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hjson</groupId>
            <artifactId>hjson</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.passay</groupId>
            <artifactId>passay</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jcl</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `Spring Boot Starter Test` has removed JUnit4 since 2.4, you have to exclude `junit-jupiter`,`junit-vintage` from `spring-boot-starter-test` in your core pom file if you wouldn't like to change your tests. Otherwise it might occur conflict issues between dependencies.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried with this, but still, the tests are failing with same error

Comment: <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
<scope>test</scope>
<exclusions>
</exclusion>
<exclusion>
<groupId>org.junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
</exclusion>
<exclusion>
<groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
<artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
</exclusion>
<exclusion>
<groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
<artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
</exclusion><exclusion>
<groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
<artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
</exclusion>
<exclusion>
<groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
<artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
</exclus

Comment: Added:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: Do you mean the JUnit with `<version>4.12</version>` solves your problem ?

Comment: No, even if I added junit <version>4.12</version>, still the tests are failing with the same error